# How to delete unwanted .csv file using matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I have 2000 .csv file obtained from weather generator to use in my simulations. All the 2000 files comes in a folder and named as:

```
r_0001_cntr_dly.csv
r_0001_scen_dly.csv
```

until

```
r_1000_cntr_dly.csv
r_1000_scen_dly.csv
```

The cntr files are the baseline data and scen files are the future climate data. I am using

```
dir('*.csv')
```

to run the simulation for the all 1000 data sets. My problem is i just need to use the "scen" file only for the simulation but the code will run all the .csv file inside the folder. Is there any easy way to delete or move "cntr" files so that the folder will only contain "scen" files for the simulation? Currently i am deleting the unwanted file manually which quite exhausting where it took me some time to delete all the 1000 files and i got many folders contains same types of file.

Thank You

Comment: `dir('*_scen_*.csv')`

Comment: so if i need the cntr file do i have to use dir('*_cntr_*.csv') ?

Comment: Also include the two stars. It actually means `_scen_` should appear between the two wildcards.

Comment: Thanks man. things are simple but im doing it in a very complicated way.

Comment: To delete - `cellfun(@(x) delete(char(x)),strcat(cellstr(pwd),filesep,ls('*cntr*.csv')))`